# two divs side by side, one fixed width, horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been answered numerous times, but still I have not found a solution for my particular situation.

I need two divs side by side, left fixed width, right flexible width. NOTE: **if the second div has long unwrappable content I need the page to have a horizontal scrollbar**.

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    left
</div>
<div class="right">
    right
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{width:50px;float:left}
.right{overflow:hidden}
```

It works, BUT if the right div has some really long unwrappable content - I want the page to have a horizontal scroll. Currently it's just CUT on the right. See https://jsfiddle.net/7qps3dm1/

PS. I know I can do it with tables.

Comment: Need a cross-browser solution if possible

Comment: Cross-browser how far back? Flexbox is available in every major browser and back to IE10

Comment: @jitbit can you clarify the content that should be included? in the question, as I've deleted my answer that doesn't answer the question for complex content

Comment: after all, if you know howto via html table, why don't you use the display behavior of table ? https://jsfiddle.net/7qps3dm1/19/

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of clearing, i suppose you need word-wrap :
https://jsfiddle.net/7qps3dm1/15/

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: blue
}
.right {
  overflow: visible;
  background: red;
  word-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_
  <img
  src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
  Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
```

---

The display table behavior from my comment :

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  background: blue
}
.right {
  background: red
}
/* lets use display:table; behavior from CSS 2.1 */
html {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table-row;
}
.left,
.right {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_</div>
```

Comment: Probably because the red content dropped below the the blue content. He asked for it to be side by side. Which to me sounds like a fixed height or something - wasn't me though ;)

Comment: @Chizzle , lol i did not notice. fixed with a margin. the question still needs clarification :), have you ever seen a word that long ;)

Comment: no I haven't seen a word that long haha. I was trying something like you did with the same idea of the margin equaling the width of the other div. I feel like I've done exactly what the OP is asking for many times by accident before, but now that I want to do it, no luck!

Comment: Actually I didn't down vote, but I did notice the image didn't stay unwrapped, which I suppose means you didn't answer the question very well, the OP needs to clarify the content before a good answer can be given, which is why I deleted my white space wrapping answer

Comment: @ToniLeigh the image and next text are meant to wrap, only this strange long word is not suppose to ;) (thought you did downvote cause your point went down at the same time  2014=>2013 & then 2012.. never mind)

Comment: @GCyrillus according to the OP there is more than just text, I'm waiting to find out what

Answer (score -1):

Using your original code with a minor adjustment:   https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/7qps3dm1/6/

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Unfortunately, this will also scroll vertically if you have line breaks in your content longer than the div height. Is that alright with you?

Comment: I need THE PAGE to be scrollable, not the div

Answer (score -1):

By using absolute positioning with an offset of the fixed width div, and `min-width: 100%;`,I was able to get the following results:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qps3dm1/20/)

```css
.left {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999999;
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right_content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="right_content"
                     >unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_content_unwrappable_con
            <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg" style=" width: 2000px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="right_content">100 % width content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```